# equivalent of !dumpheap -stat on native side

Tags: c++, windbg, crash-dumps

I would like inspect native heap of process to see what native classes are present in memory and what are their size. Its equivalent to sos !dumpheap -stat command. Is it possible to do it on the native side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that the reason you want to inspect native heap is to analyze heap usage and possibly figure out what is the nature of the allocations on the heap and what part of code is responsible for that. If so, the output from [umdh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947(v=vs.85).aspx) tool is the closest I can think of. It is much more verbose than `!dumpheap -stat`, but you can get much more from it -- e.g. you can pinpoint exact code that is responsible for allocations by looking at the allocation call stacks.

Normally Umdh is used for memory leak diagnostics. To get breakdown of all allocations in the process you will need to use so called single-dump mode.

Although the output of Umdh won't tell you directly what is the native type being allocated, in most cases you can derive it easily from the allocation call stack. For example, in this snippet from Umdh output there are 0x4a allocations consuming a total of 0x194b0 bytes, and type of allocations are easy to figure out, since `std::vector<unsinged short>` are in the call stack, and allocation was done within method RecordData::Deserialize.

`+   194b0 ( 194b0 -     0)     4a allocs    BackTraceD0F18F8
+      4a (    4a -     0)  BackTraceD0F18F8    allocations`

```
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+36991
MSVCR120D!_heap_alloc_base+51 (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\heap\malloc.c, 58)
MSVCR120D!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl+1FF (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c, 431)
MSVCR120D!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl+1D (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c, 239)
MSVCR120D!_nh_malloc_dbg+2A (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c, 302)
MSVCR120D!malloc+19 (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgmalloc.c, 56)
MSVCR120D!operator new+F (f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\heap\new.cpp, 59)
STestViewer!std::_Allocate<unsigned short>+2F (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0, 28)
STestViewer!std::allocator<unsigned short>::allocate+19 (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0, 578)
STestViewer!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<unsigned short> >::allocate+1A (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0, 848)
STestViewer!std::vector<unsigned short,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_Reallocate+57 (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector, 1588)
STestViewer!std::vector<unsigned short,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_Reserve+5A (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector, 1619)
TestViewer!std::vector<unsigned short,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::resize+FC (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector, 1136)
TestViewer!RecordData::Deserialize+52 (c:\src\stcommonlib\stdmodel.cpp, 174)
TestViewer!SensorDrModel::LoadFromFile+21E (c:\src\stcommonlib\stsmodel.cpp, 50)
```

In other cases the type of object is not obvious from call stack, but since you have source file name and line number what invoked `operator new`, you can establish that by looking at the source code.

To **summarize** what you get with Umdh:

1. This is **not** a direct analog of !dumpheap.
2. You will spend much more time with this, because it is very verbose.
3. However you can extract information about the reason why allocations happened in the first place, which you cannot do from !dumpheap.

Comment: Although the original question is tagged [crash-dump] which I consider as post-mortem debugging, and the information is not included there, I wanted to post the same thing, because it definitely is an option if it can be reproduced in a live environment. +1

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no. You can look through the heap and see the *sizes* of allocated blocks, but one of the basic facts of life of native code is that you can't depend on it to put type-tags into allocated objects, so an object on the heap generally doesn't contain enough information to figure out its type.

When you're dealing with something like the Windows GDI heap (which does put type tags into allocated objects) you can do this, but for other code that just allocates and uses memory, the information you'd need just doesn't exist.

I should probably add: if you have debugging information (and little concern for execution speed) it's probably possible to trace allocations and the types to which they're assigned, so you'd be able to work backward from allocated chunks of memory to actual object types. Some heap debugging tools have done things at least similar to this, though I'm not aware of any that does exactly what you're asking for.